# Как в EntityFramework Core использовать два свойства одного типа?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Пытаюсь понять, возможно ли реализовать в EF Core такое отношение (код не из предметной области):

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; init; }

    public User SimpleUser { get; set; }
    public User AdminUser { get; set; }

    private Company() { }

    public Company(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; init; }

    private User() { }

    public User(string name, Company company)
    {
        Name = name;
        Company = company;
    }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Во-первых, я не могу понять, какое здесь отношение. Один-к-одному, один-ко-многим или многие-ко-многим?

С конфигурацией по умолчанию при создании миграции появляется ошибка:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Company.AdminUser' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Похожий вопрос был задан здесь:

[How to use EF Core when two properties in the Principle entity point to the same attribute in the dependent entity?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/610783/how-to-use-ef-core-when-two-properties-in-the-prin)

Его решение в использовании InverseProperty. Однако в вопросе структура класса несколько отличается от моего. По ссылке класс содержит одно свойство, содержащее тип Faculty, и второе свойство, содержащее **список** Faculty. Мне не удалось правильно применить указанный метод.

Любые соображения приветствуются.

Comment: Так в тексте ошибки написано-же, что необходимо либо вручную сконфигурировать отношение, либо проигнорировать его. Каким образом Вы задаёте отношения между сущностями? В приведённом Вами коде аннотаций нет. Если используете FluentAPI, то приведите его. Отношение (по представленной Вами структуре) один-к-одному, т.е. одна компания имеет одного админа, а админ только одну компанию, то-же самое с обычным пользователем.

Comment: Вы можете привести более конкретные рекомендации?

Comment: Если конкретно, то для определения отношений между сущностями используйте [FluentAPI](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api).

Comment: Обычно у юзера делают свойство Role. И уже в роли задано, кто это. А у компании просто список юзеров.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь модель языка программирования напрямую перенести в модель базы данных. А это чаще всего невозможно (или очень сложно). Этому даже есть специальное название: [Object–relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_impedance_mismatch)

Comment: @XelaNimed , какие Ваши дальнейшие рекомендации? Использовать EF Core? C#? Клавиатуру? Я знаю, что отношения можно определять через FluentAPI. Как это сделать в конкретной описанной ситуации? Я не исключаю, что подобное отношение реализовать невозможно. Такой ответ будет вполне приемлемым. Но пока что Ваши комментарии похожи на флуд.

Comment: @alexander-petrov , спасибо за комментарий. Да, мне известен этот термин. И я вполне допускаю, что желаемое отображение невозможно. Я просмотрел документацию и не нашел там ничего похожего. Первое решение, о котором я подумал, как раз использование ролей. Вопрос был задан по двум причинам. 
1. Проблема по ссылке показалась мне схожей. 
2. Не хочется зависеть от протекающих абстракций. Я понимаю, что ORM это весьма условная абстракция над БД. Но EF дает много возможностей для абстрагирования. Хотелось использовать их по максимуму.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53793988/5045688

Comment: @alexander-petrov , спасибо. Да, это примерно то, что позволило получить желаемый результат. Подход не самый практичный, но это было ожидаемо. Занятно, что мне уже приходилось читать о такой проблеме. В статье, в которой обсуждалось несоответствие объектно-реляционного импеданса ( https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/modeling-relationships-in-ddd-way/ ). Автор, как и Вы, призывает «всегда делать отношения однонаправленными, когда это возможно».